# Multithreading "unpredictable" behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

I was going through the use cases for volatile and I have encountered the below scenario:

```
private static boolean stop = false;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread runner = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(!stop){
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("I m done after "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        }
    });

    runner.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    stop = true;
}
```

The above code runs indefinitely. Which is fine due to **hoisting** done by the compiler in an attempt to optimize the code. However, if I replace, **i++** with some other statement e.g. **System.out.println("Hello")**. It stops after 2 seconds.

Why the behavior is like this? I am using jdk1.7.0_51.

**Note:** 
I know I should declare *stop* as volatile. However, I would like to know the reason for the behavior in the above case.

Comment: from a lame point of view, increasing a value is is easier than writing to stream. :).

Comment: One reason I can think of is that i++ is converted into Java Byte Code which doesn't use I/O where as System.out.println is actually I/O. This may give enough time to see the change in boolean variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard output is a shared resource across threads. Java's `PrintStream` class is made thread-safe using synchronized blocks, and all synchronized blocks are memory barriers in java, that's why changes on the `stop` field become visible inside the loop. However, you shouldn't rely on this.

For example, take a look at the `PrintStream.println` implementation:

```
public void println(String paramString)
{
  synchronized (this)
  {
    print(paramString);
    newLine();
  }
}
```